# How long is a draft question preserved, and where do I find it?

Tags: support, questions, draft

I hit the [six question limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374325/233154) and cannot post my most important question of the month.

SE says my post is saved as a draft.

How long will it be accessible, and where do I fish it out to post it when the system lets me post?

Comment: It will be removed [after a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236634). You can view it in the ask page.

Comment: @double-beep Thanks!  Where is the "ask page" ?  (I looked in my profile, and such a page did not jump out at me.)  You mean when I press the Ask button I will see the draft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111050/282094