# What happened to the "discard" button?

Tags: support, draft

Often I start typing a question on SO and then figure out the answer halfway through. I used to just click discard, but lately it seems to have vanished. Where did it go?

Comment: @Emrakul we have draft on questions too, and a special tag for [meta-tag:draft].

Comment: @Sha Oh, cool, didn't realize. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The discard link only appears after a draft has been saved.

If a draft hasn't yet been saved, there's nothing to discard so no need for it. Just type in some text in an answer box and wait for a minute ([45 seconds in fact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/158667)), you'll see the link appear.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a few letters (even one letter as [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158667/mat) explained) in the answer too alongwith some time for waiting.

A single line paragraph, such as my first paragraph won't make the answer to be (draft word appeared at this stage) saved as a draft.

But since this line, it appears! Saving the answer so that in case of any error your answer stays here safe. Which is a helpfull element for this website too! But, wait for it.

Try looking at the network tab to check all the network requests. And note the link that's known as `answer`. That is the link which ensures that the answer was sent. It is located at `editor-heartbeat`.

[image]

It generally takes 45 seconds for this request. So you need to wait atleast 45 seconds and check what happens. Discard will appear after the response from this link. Which is a result of whether you were writing an answer or not.

Comment: I get a discard link even if I just type a single letter in the answer box.

Comment: But you still have to wait for 45 seconds don't you! :) I kept writing the answer and the draft appeared at the spot I mentioned..

Comment: Yes, but your first line seems to indicate otherwise ("need to have a few words").

Comment: Yes of course, :) I have edited the answer as per your suggestion :)

Comment: Body of a post must contain at least 30 characters (try to type less and see what happens when you submit) so no point saving draft before you reach 30 characters. :)

Comment: But @Mat corrected me out saying that only 1 letter would do the trick. Who's correct? ShaWizDowArd :/ ?

Comment: Just try it out, you'll see for yourself.

Comment: Hey @ShaWizDowArd, Mat is right. I just wrote `My Name is...` and it got saved :/

Comment: Cool, glad to stand corrected!