# Seeking to reduce Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange suspension period?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, account-suspension, ban

I've been suspended for a week on Stack Overflow.

Is there any way to reduce this suspension period on Stack Overflow or any suspension period on any site in the Stack Exchange network?

I've replied to the moderators but they are not replying me back?

Comment: You can't. You just have to wait.

Comment: I've tried to submit answers to some more questions but I can't submit. will the answer still be saved in the editor till my suspension ends? Cause if i open the question again I can see my answers in editor.

Comment: You're looking at the saved draft feature. That is not meant to be a permanent storage. You better save that answer locally and post it after your suspension has ended

Comment: The draft is saved for 7 days, but there can be only one single draft per site. More details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/152859). /cc @rene

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's useful info..thanks.. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there any way to reduce this suspension period?

You can respond to the moderators. But that doesn't mean that it will be shortened - this is entirely to the discretion of the moderators.

They are unlikely to reverse a decision to suspend, as suspensions are taken very seriously by them and are not just handed out willy nilly.

Comment: I replied to moderators but they are not replying to me? what can i do now? I can't send another message till they replay to original message.

Comment: You will have to wait for the moderators to see it and respond back. Some moderators will not respond if they believe the appropriate action has been taken and there is nothing more to say. In general - you got suspended, most likely for a good reason, meaning you need to wait out your suspension period. Take this as a learning experience.

Comment: @Kylo I agree with Oded here, probably the moderator(s) see no point engaging in endless and pointless discussion that can't end well, when their decision is final.

Comment: I'll be honest, we don't often reply to responses from people suspended for voting fraud. We've found that this is almost always a waste of our time, and regularly leads to insults and threats against us (like the one I just got in my inbox now). We only tend to lift suspensions in cases where we've made a mistake, but as that is not the case here, I don't think the moderator involved will do so.

Comment: As a Moderator, I am here to answer questions and provide clarification... but I can't always continue endlessly with a back-and-forth debate once the conversation starts to repeat itself — e.g.  *"User: I think I should be un-suspended."* Me: You were suspended you for reason {x} and {y}. *"User: I think I should be un-suspended!"* — Sometimes you just have to agree to disagree and move on.

Comment: @BradLarson I respect SO policies and your role as moderators. But for me the case was how to deal with a more experienced user that is down voting my question/answers over some arguments which the couldn't win. Obviously SO work as a religion where crowd will follow the influence people(reputation here). A question stated with a up vote has a tendency to follow by more up votes and vice versa too. For a user just started on community it's a miracle if other experienced user doesn't see his answer with skeptical view and not try to teach him remaining part, which i'm not saying is wrong. :)

Comment: @BradLarson For example look at Dennis's answer(following link) he has not answered very accurately(and i'm not saying he is wrong) or the actual confined boundaries of the question but since he got a high rep, it's just more & more votes for him over time. but look at the question it has started negative and i'm very sure that how will it go. I know this is not a very good analogy I'm presenting but I'm sure you'll be able to see my point.(wrong question: right answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084542/mvvm-viewmodel-and-type-of-property-presentationcore-dll

Comment: @RobertCartaino I get your point and I learned my lesson. But I share my posts with a group of friends and they share their posts with me, who works/used to work with me on the same projects/technologies so over the period of time if you see a voting pattern between some of users will I'll be suspended again? I'm sure the reputation of users will play a role here