# To whom is a saved draft visible?

Tags: support, draft

I just would like to know if a question or an answer saved draft is visible to someone else, apart from the OP.

Will a copy of a saved draft remain visible even after it has been deleted? Who has access to it?

Comment: In theory to devs and in practice to anyone who can sniff your network traffic between your PC and the SE servers.

Comment: ....and in practice? What about mods for instance?

Comment: That is in my comment ...

Comment: Moderators have no access to this, I'm 99.999% sure of this.

Comment: and who has access to a saved draft in the SE community?

Comment: I've said in theory devs, because I think Oded told me once that the drafts go into Redis but they have no CRUD interface on that so it isn't easy accessible for dev or SRE's, let alone moderators or CM's.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238 doesn't answer the who exactly has access. And as it is in Redis I don't expect it to exist anymore once it has been expired from the cache.

Comment: +1 it's never occurred to me ask that question before.  Informative answer by Oded

Answer (score 14):

Technically speaking, the draft is saved against your user in redis for a week, meaning that when you get back to the site, even on a different browser/computer, so long as you are logged in, it can be recovered (within that week timeframe).

No one but you can see the draft, with a caveat.

This does mean, that given your user details, a developer who has access to production redis can figure out the key for a draft and look for it. We don't have an easy UI to do so - which is very much by design, so if someone were inclined to do so they would have to do some work before being able to retrieve draft details. But we have better things to do...

Comment: sorry , no computer nerd here, so you mean that only the OP can see and read the draft. No mods or other privileged users can see it. In my experience a draft will expire in a couple of days..not  a week.

Comment: @Mr.Black - should be a week. But the answer that yes, apart from developers and some other Stack Overflow employees, no one has access to the data, and even us developers and employees can't access it easily.

Comment: OK thanks, but believe me..it is not a week. A couple of days at most.

Comment: Believe Oded, it is a week @Mr.Black

Comment: well, in that case it works differently for me. I often use the saved draft function for questions and it ***never*** lasted for more than 2 days.

Comment: Then post a separate question if you want to to report that as a bug @Mr.Black

Comment: @Mr.Black It's couple of days because you write new questions or answers each time, which overwrites the draft. There is one single draft for questions, and one single draft for answers. You do not have draft for each answer you write, only the last.