# Please reduce the timer for _cross site_ consecutive questions

Tags: feature-request

The time limit between asking questions is *40 minutes!!*. This applies to all sites alike. I am on some 5 sites [linked with one account]. Asking the question on one site sets the clock ticking on all. This is a little too much, because I frequently have questions to ask on more than one site *at the same time*. Waiting for 40 minutes, I sometimes forget the question altogether.

- Despite the merits of keeping a timer like this, can we reduce its length at least for *cross-site* consecutive questions?

Comment: The cross-site timer is already less than half the same-site timer (which is 90 minutes).

Comment: @animuson I never _knew_ the same site timer is 90 minutes.

Comment: But still maybe 40 minutes is a bit too much

Comment: What do you propose would be a reasonable length of time?

Comment: Not sure maybe 20 minutes or less

Comment: As well, [40 minutes was picked for a reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) - that's the amount of time it takes 75% of negatively scoring questions to get their first downvote. Lowering it would only increase the number of poor questions network-wide.

Comment: This rate limit only applies as long as you have less than 125 rep as far as I know. Earning that amount of rep is the easiest way to get around this limit.

Comment: I suppose it's just one of those "this is why we can't have nice things" things that you'll have to deal with. Too many people causing too many problems does make it kind of stink for the rare few that wouldn't cause any problems, which is too bad, but unavoidable.

Comment: Please, I beg of you, do not call Stack Exchange sites forums. According to Jeff Atwood (https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/), "There's far too much great programming information trapped in forums, buried in online help, or hidden away in books that nobody buys any more. We'd like to unlock all that." Stack Exchange is a family of Q&A sites that help to solve the problems with forums. They are *not* forums themselves.

Comment: @Mad Scientist getting 125 rep on one site solves the problem for _cross site_ consecutive questions of _all sites_ ?

Comment: @zondo It really doesn't matter, since it's clear what is being talked about. Just edit the post if it bugs you. No matter what anybody calls it, they'll eventually fall into the appropriate use patterns and terminology here without needing to be told at every opportunity.

Comment: @JasonC: People treating SE like a forum (like posting new questions as answers) is a problem. The less we talk about it like it is, the better.

Comment: If you forget the question after only 40 minutes.. was it really a useful question, in the first place?

Comment: @Gnemlock That's the same thing I have been asking myself. And I think it was useful in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're basically talking about an edge case. I took a look at your sites, and I admit, it's somewhat difficult to cross post between them.

> 40 minutes

20 minutes less than lunch hour. I can see this being a problem if you ask all your questions during lunch.

> I frequently have questions to ask on more than one site at the same time

This is actually quite unusual. Do you have a pressing need for multiple, interlinked questions to be answered all at once?

> I sometimes forget the question altogether.

[SE saves drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting). OK, *one* draft per site. Or you could compose the question off-site and paste/polish it.

Also, SE isn't a forum. In a practical sense, SE's designed to try to minimise as much of the noise of forums as possible

Comment: They are not linked. But I frequently have some questions to be asked. Then I decide I will ask them at the same time [ free time ]. But frustratingly it turns out I cant.