# Access drafts across different computers

Tags: support, bug, draft

According to the quotation at the end of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/354801)

> For anonymous we use cookie to track the user. For
>   non anonymous **we use the user id**

...when saving drafts to new questions or answers.

As my id is linked to my account, not my computer or browser session, I would expect therefore that drafts created on, say, my desktop computer would also be accessible on my laptop (within the 7 day grace period)

However in my experience, a draft of a new question will not make it from one computer to another, even when I'm signed in on both. Is this a bug or am I misinterpreting the intended behaviour?

Running Google Chrome Windows 10 on both computers, full specs if you need them.