# When trying to print out questions, why is the content shifted to the left?

Tags: discussion, design

I am not interested in a plugin to do a fancy print, I'd just like for the content to be spread out on the page.

I have hopefully attached a page from each of the four sites I recently joined to illustrate the issue. I print because, so far, I find no bookmark capability here.

Instead I have found if I record the question number. Google will find it usually first: sustainability 4974
or for sure with: sustainability "/questions/4974"

[image: Sustainable Living]

[image: WorldBuilding]

[image: Meta]

[image: Community Building]

[image: Stack Overflow]

Comment: When you look at the question then just below the voting arrows there should be a star. If you click it the question becomes one of your favourites. Does this help with your bookmarking problem?

Comment: @mdewey I thought that star was for Voting or something I couldn't do yet...thanks a lot. Now if you can just explain where my draft question went, and how to get it back, I will be forever in your debt (I really hate to redo my work!)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Comment: @Bart Found it but needed to go through the search process again before it turned up. The title was lost as I entered a new search (same as last time), but the balance of the draft was there and not needing to be reentered( I usually find a redo is not as good as the first draft, maybe it's my desire to recall just exactly the words I used the first time, that will, of course never materialize again when you want them to).

Comment: @mdeway Thanks too, no more in your debt.... :-)