# Allow automatic draft saving to be turned off

Tags: feature-request, draft

There is a limitation in the amount of drafts, only one per user.

From [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

> - You only get one draft for an answer and one for a question. (If you start a new post, the old draft is cleared.)

The problem of this limitation for having only a single draft available is that users can see their drafts being lost because the system automatically overwrites them without confirmation (at least this happened to me, where I saved and left a question, and in the meantime continued answering other questions).

This is very unintuitive. You would not expect a draft to be overwritten (ie being lost) without consent.

Overwriting an old draft should at least be warned for before the draft is allowed to be overwritten, and ideally it should be possible to turn of the system that automatically saves the drafts such that you can not get an unexpected overwritten draft.

Comment: This only happens for answers, right?

Comment: @Glorfindel yes.

Comment: I don't create so many questions in order to know this.

Comment: Well, the whole drafts feature is something that was done over 8 years ago, probably without much planning, got almost no attention since then. To make real changes, they probably need to rewrite the whole things and this, well, takes lots of time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I would understand that. a short fix is to alter the message when you leave a page (which only say that changes may get lost, but not that the draft gets completely lost) to include information that the draft gets overwritten when you start a new answer/question elsewhere.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings yeah this would have better chance to be done.