# Are answer drafts kept if a question is deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, draft

Say I am writing an answer and it is successfully saved as a draft. Then the OP deletes the question before I post my draft. What happens then? Is my draft available anywhere? Will I see it if I am a 10K user that can see the deleted question? Will the draft show again if the question is undeleted?

The [draft specs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/209901) do not mention deleted questions, so it is a blur area to me.

This comes from the question [Los borradores de respuestas, ¿se pierden si OP elimina la pregunta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4362/1674) in Meta Spanish.SE, where a 10K user cannot see their draft anymore.

Comment: You will not see it, not even as a 10K user, while deleted because deleted questions don't have answer boxes that can show drafts. I'm not sure if it will reappear upon undeletion :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *should* still see the draft if a question goes through a delete / undelete cycle, but that's more of an artifact of how drafts currently work than a deliberate feature, so I'm not sure it will always remain that way.

I'm also not 100% certain how often orphan drafts are culled, so if you were *almost* done writing an epic answer to something and notice its existence come into question, maybe save it safely in a text file somewhere if it could be useful in the future.

tl;dr: Yes, it should work, but in six to eight arbitrary units of time it might not.

Comment: If the OP deletes their own question, this looks different from other types of deletion. Is there still a draft somewhere in that case?

Comment: @aschepler Yes. That's exactly the case described in the question. It would also work if, say, a moderator deleted the question (with the same disclaimer: it's not promised behavior, so the behavior could be subject to change).

Answer (score 1):

I think it will. I recently wrote a draft on a question about [Bricks SE](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/), the OP accidentally deleted (and undeleted) their question twice, and my answer draft came back - but only if the "Draft Saved"  message appeared:

[image]