# Users should be able to save an answer draft on a closed question if it's edited for reopening

Tags: feature-request, edits, answers, closed-questions, draft

I recently came across a question that had been closed for being unclear, but I think I knew what the asker meant, so I edited the question and checked the box to have it reviewed for reopening.

I wanted to answer, but now I will have to wait to see whether the question gets reopened before I can even start writing my answer.

We could argue, in this particular case, that only the asker knows about their question and it's up to them to add clarifying details. However, the same situation applies in other cases, such as:

- when the asker edits a question to address the close reason, or
- when someone else edits it to address it based on the asker's comments, or
- when the original closure reason was incorrect (i.e. it was closed as a duplicate and the asker edits in why none of the answers in the target worked for them).

In any case, users cannot begin to write an answer until the question is fully reopened.

I suggest that when a user makes an edit and checks the box saying the question should be reopened then anyone should be able to save an answer draft, and if they do so then they should be notified when, and if, the question is reopened so that they can post their answer (providing that the question has not been further edited).

It would be great for saving time.

Comment: Opposite question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/282094 and almost similar question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353690/282094 --- you can use a different question, even a different site (such as one with MathJax enabled), to compose your question using the Stack Exchange editor and then save it locally in your own text editor; in the unlikely event that the question was closed incorrectly or prematurely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an edit clarifies the question well (which leads to it being reopened) then it should be possible for other knowledgeable users to answer the question as well (and their answers may be better).

Therefore, it seems to be a waste of time and effort to draft a full answer immediately.

I think it would be better to create a Saves list called "Draft answers", for example, and add the question there with a private note full of hints about the approach to giving the answer.

If a user wanted to be notified when the question is reopened then I think that checking the Follow option under the question is the way to go.

The best way here to save time (which is a justification given in the last line) is to avoid drafting an answer to a question that has not yet been reopened.

Answer (score 6):

I think the principle that should apply here is that until the community decides that a closed question is suitable for re-opening, usually by it being improved through editing, we should not encourage its answering.

If, nevertheless, a user wishes to commence a draft answer then that should only be performed offline from the Stack Exchange network, perhaps using a text editor like Notepad.