# Support saving self-answered questions as drafts

Tags: feature-request, editor, self-answer, draft

Drafts of unsubmitted questions and answers on Stack Exchange are automatically saved every 45 seconds. However, saved drafts [don't support self-answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/351462). This means if you leave the ask page while working on a post, the question will be saved as a draft but the self-answer will be lost.

Are there any plans to support saving self-answered questions as drafts?

Comment: Did this post get linked from somewhere? I'm seeing a few votes come in after months of inactivity.

Comment: It got linked in our work Slack, after another staff member encountered a similar issue (albeit on Teams) of losing the draft of the self-answer they'd been writing. I'm guessing that's why :P